# HttpListener throwing HttpListenerException (400) while reading input stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, httplistener

I have this very simple C# code *that runs in .NET 5.0* and listens on port 80:

```
// Create a listener.
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
// Add the prefixes.
listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://*:80/");
listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening... <CTRL+C to quit>");

while (true)
{
    // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request.
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    string requestContent;
    string responseContent = null;

    using (var inputStream = request.InputStream)
    {
        using (var inputStreamReader =
                   new System.IO.StreamReader(inputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            requestContent = inputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    if (condition)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff}] " +
                          $"Receveid request from {request.RemoteEndPoint}: " +
                          $"{requestContent}");

        // ...statements...

        responseContent = "...";

        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff}] " +
                          $"Response: {responseContent}");

        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    else
    {
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    }


    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent ?? string.Empty);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    response.OutputStream.Close();
}
```

It works fine, but sometimes it throws and exits. The error is the following:

> Unhandled exception. System.Net.HttpListenerException (400): Unknown
> error 400    at System.Net.HttpRequestStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at
> System.Net.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> size)    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()    at
> System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()    at
> TradingBot.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /home/teejay/MyProgram/Program.cs:line 138

I confronted the reference source of .NET 4.8 but the `ReadCore` seems not to exist. Maybe it was introduced in .NET 5.0 for which I can't find the reference source.

Anyway looking for `HttpListenerException` at `HttpRequestStream` .NET 4.8 source didn't help, there are 3 matches but I can't understand what's going on in that code.

I know that I can add a try catch block, and I'll do, but I want to understand the cause of that error. It's strange that a listening server throws a 400 while reading the input stream, isn't it?

Comment: The response is different when fails than when passes.  Capture good and bad results and save as text.  Then compare good and bad to see differences.  We cannot help unless we know the difference between the good and bad results.  With error 400 usually there is no results.  What you probably are seeing is an error message in the body of the response and not a good response.  The 400 error is returned from the server so you are getting an error in the server.

Comment: If you look at the stacktrade, it seems that the exception is thrown at `requestContent = inputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();` so *before* testing the condition and computing the response. The server has been tested with *condition* true or false and it works fine every time. But sometimes a request arrives (maybe from port scanners on the internet, or some bad request) that crashes the server.

Comment: Do failure occur on all clients or only some clients?  Set condition to false at top (then true after readtoend()) of while loop so if you fail you send a failure.  What version of Net are you using for compiling?  Make sure you are using 4.7.2 or later which resolve issues with targeting Core.

Comment: I'm using the newest .NET 5.

Comment: You should use the operationg system for TLS instead of Net by modifying your app config file.  See : https://domburf.medium.com/enabling-tls-1-2-on-your-net-application-5e4663d18a96.  If you have a mobile device you should make sure the Kernel is updated to enable the latest encryption modes.

Comment: I know how to enable TLS 1.2, I did it recently on a application of mine. But I don't see how this relates with my problem. I am accepting connections, not doing them.

Comment: You still have to be able to decrypt receive messages.   You could be using a certificte with an encryption mode that isn't supported byu the version of Net youi are using.  With TLS the server sends a certificate block to client with a list of certificate names that can be used.  Somebody could of loaded a certificate in the server with an encrptionmodes that your version of Net doesn't support.